What is the proper use of insults?
I'm trying to understand the ethical use of insults and inflammatory language. How can I know when I ought to be offensive and when I ought to avoid it? There seems to be a tension within the Bible on this. For example, consider Jesus's words in Matt.5:22

Whoever insults his brother will be liable to the council, and whoever says, 'you fool!' will be liable to the hell of fire.

There are other passages which, in isolation, would seem to prohibit all use of insulting or offensive language:

In your hearts honor Christ the Lord as holy, always being prepared to make a defense to anyone who asks you for a reason for the hope that is in you; yet do it with gentleness and respect. (1 Peter 3:15)


Whoever belittles his neighbor lacks sense,
but a man of understanding remains silent. (Proverbs 11:12)


A soft answer turns away wrath, but a harsh word stirs up anger. (Proverbs 15:1)


Be angry and do not sin; do not let the sun go down on your anger... Let no corrupting talk come out of your mouths, but only such as is good for building up, as fits the occasion, that it may give grace to those who hear. (Galatians 4:26&29)


With [the tongue] we bless our Lord and Father, and with it we curse people who are made in the likeness of God. From the same mouth come blessing and cursing. My brothers, these things ought not to be so. (James 3:9-10)

At the same time, we also read in the Bible many instances of Jesus and the apostles using insults:
(From Jesus:)

You are of your father the devil, and your will is to do your father's desires. (John 8:25)


You Pharisees cleanse the outside of the cup and of the dish, but inside you are full of greed and wickedness. You fools! (Luke 11:39-40; in this whole paragraph Jesus is not very polite)


You brood of vipers! How can you speak good, when you are evil? (Matt.12:34)

(From others:)

"You brood of vipers! Who warned you to flee from the wrath to come?" (Luke 3:7)


O foolish Galatians! Who has bewitched you? (Gal. 3:1)


I wish those who trouble you would emasculate themselves! (Gal.5:12)


I have written something to the church, but Diotrephes, who likes to put himself first, does not acknowledge our authority. (3 John 10)


These [false teachers] are hidden reefs at your love feasts, as they feast with you without fear, shepherds feeding themselves; waterless clouds, swept along by winds; fruitless trees in late autumn, twice dead, uprooted; wild waves of the sea, casting up the foam of their own shame; wandering stars, for whom the gloom of utter darkness has been reserved forever...These are grumblers, malcontents, following their own sinful desires; they are loud-mouthed boasters  showing favoritism to gain advantage. (Jude 12-13,16)

I could go on with many more examples but I think these suffice to prove the point that Jesus and the apostles did use insults and harsh words at times.
I am wondering if anyone can point me to some good resources dealing with this tension. Are there any works by respectable Christian authors dealing with the issue of the proper use of insults and/or offensive language? I am coming from a Reformed perspective, but if anyone can recommend resources from other denominations as well, I would certainly take a look! To be clear about what I am asking, I'm not simply asking for a resolution of the apparent tension, but also for a practical set of principles to know when it is right to offend people.

Update: Since some have taken issue with my use of the word "insult", I ought to explain why I think it's the right word here. Jesus knowingly used language that was offensive to his listeners, and not just mildly so. If you want to call it a "rebuke" instead of an "insult" that's OK, but it doesn't change the underlying question I have, which is basically to what extent should I try to avoid offending people, and on the flipside, and when should I knowingly be impolite, as Jesus undeniably was on some occasions.

Did use insults (sic). No, they did not ! You are confusing 'insults' with facts. When people are being warned of their outrageous behaviour and the consequences of that behaviour, that is not insulting. It could result in their penitence, their salvation and their eternal glory.

An act, or the action, of insulting (in sense 1 or 2a of vb.); injuriously contemptuous speech or behaviour; scornful utterance or action intended to wound self-respect; an affront, indignity, outrage. Oxford English Dictionary.

So calling someone a fool is not an insult, then?

Note that OED's definition makes no reference to whether the offensive statement is true or false. I am not saying that what Jesus and the apostles said in those passages was false but rather that it was offensive to some people, and deliberately so.

If someone is doing foolish things, then they are a fool. That is a statement of fact. The OED defines 'wounding' 'scornful' 'contemptuous' 'indignity'. None of these are present in the rebukes you comment upon. They are not insults. They are rebukes of behaviour and rebukes against words spoken. They are not personal insults. No epithets are being delivered ; only statements of historic fact regarding conduct and speech.

"You are evil" is not an insult? I'm sorry but I don't think I follow. Also, if we define insult in such a way that it excludes true statements, that doesn't resolve the tension that I have pointed out. Jesus said not to call people fools but he did it himself.

Jesus warned not to call a brother (note well, a brother) a more. But God calls the rich barn-builder an aphron. One needs to be careful what one is saying, here. I suggest some more research is needed for this question.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

related: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/52469/18064

there are actually a bunch of questions relating to several of the verses in question: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/34284/why-did-jesus-say-to-call-someone-a-fool-puts-you-in-danger-of-hell, https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/11438/in-matthew-1234-what-did-jesus-mean-when-he-called-the-pharisees-a-brood-of-vi, https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/22261/what-did-jesus-mean-by-fool-in-matthew-522

Please see the same question asked in SE-Biblical Hermeneutics and my answer to it.

To the person that voted to close. How is the question "Are there any works by respectable Christian authors dealing with the issue of the proper use of insults and/or offensive language?" likely to generate opinionated answers?

@NigelJ, in your linked BH answer, you say "This is a matter between brethren. It is not a matter of distant strangers falling out.", and I'd agree with that. But in your comments above you say that Jesus did not use insults, and I have to disagree, as the quotations in the Question clearly are insults, and intended as such.

@RayButterworth Not according to the Oxford English Dictionary.

@NigelJ — If someone said to you "you are full of greed and wickedness", or "you fool", or "you are evil", I would certainly think they were deliberately insulting you, and I suspect you would feel that you had been insulted. What in the OED specifically denies that these are insults?

@RayButterworth You are using the English word 'fool'. I suggest you concentrate on the meaning of the Greek text for the sake of precision and clarity. You are also using the word 'insult' contrary to its lexical definition.

Examples where what seems like detraction/railing is not sinful.

Your actual que is :when is mockery and abuse justified?

A basic problem in understanding the biblical use of language we consider to be offensive today is that of piezogesis - squeezing scripture into preconceived ideas / doctrines / practices.  In this case, using our preconceived, modern ideas about the practice of language, as to what is acceptable or unacceptable, and looking at the scriptures in light of that, instead of starting with how language was used in scripture, as the inspired record gives us today.
The 'squeezing' of scripture happens most seriously if the holy Bible is viewed as only 'containing' the word of God, as opposed to the Reformed Protestant view that every word is the inspired word of God. I assume you hold to the latter view, which is why an answer can be given to this question.
As the Westminster Confession of Faith states here, after listing the 66 books of the Bible acclaimed as inspired of God by Reformed Protestants:

"1.2 All which are given by inspiration of God, to be the rule of
faith and life."
"1.4 The authority of the holy Scriptures, for which it ought to be
believed and obeyed, dependeth not upon the testimony of any man or
church, but wholly upon God (who is truth itself), the author thereof;
and therefore it is to be received, because it is the word of God."
The Westminster Confession of Faith

If some parts of those scriptures are viewed as man's ideas, or words, and therefore disputable or unnecessary, then their Holy-Spirit inspired meaning and significance will never be understood. Further, if Jesus Christ is viewed as being a great man but not God incarnate, his words will be understood in light of how modern man views things; they will judge Jesus' words and decide for themselves what is acceptable language, and what is not. Yet given that the Jesus who walked on Earth is the eternal Son of God who authorizes him to judge every person who has ever lived on the Day of Judgment, his critical, strong words to merely religious people back then must be viewed as the words of God.
Alas, today we live in a Politically Correct era where most people are frightened to say "Boo!" to a goose. Anyone offering criticism to other people or groups, with words that are deemed not to conform to their nation's standards (which are worldly, not godly) can find themselves in court. Censorship of language has even now encroached into freedom of speech to express what one believes, including even praying silently in public in some area in the country I live in. Many of the words of our Lord (which you give examples of) are extremely offensive to most people today. Yet he is the very Word of God! His words are life, and truth, for he is "the way, and the truth, and the life." That includes the truth he unapologetically spoke to those who would not accept him as the Son of God.
A clear distinction needs to be made between his words, and the way people speak today, surely? He had divine authority to rebuke and even to condemn individuals and groups. We do not have that authority. Which is where the other verses listed in the question come in. Christians are to heed the command to be respectful and reasonable in responding to others. But we can, and should, quote Jesus' words appropriately, even if that causes us to be viewed with contempt or hatred by others. The key word there is 'appropriately'.
So, my answer to your question is that Christians are never to insult others. Even Michael the archangel, when disputing with Satan, "durst not bring against him a railing accusation, but said, 'The Lord rebuke thee'." (Jude verse 9 A.V.) However, Jesus has all authority in Heaven and on Earth to rebuke and to accuse, so that all such words of his may be quoted by Christians, if quoted appropriately and in a spirit of humility, not arrogance, or superiority.
P.S. re. 'respectable Christian authors' writing on the topic, there are a few points dotted throughout chapter 17 (The Church) in 'Pilgrim Theology' by Michael Horton, 2011, Zondervan. One such snippet is on page 415 where it defines the difference between extraordinary and ordinary ministry, part of which says:
"Applied to the Spirit's ministry in the history of revelation, this distinction holds that the extraordinary ministry of the prophets and apostles is qualitatively distinct from the ordinary ministry of the pastors, elders, and deacons who followed the foundation-laying era of the old and new covenants."

I think this is a good answer, but are you implying that what Jesus said would not have been considered offensive back then? I don't think that makes sense, especially considering that people actually were offended. To the point of actually putting him to death, though admittedly that wasn't just because he called them fools. (Come to think of it, I'm not sure cancel culture today is quite as bad as that...)

@DarkMalthorp  Jesus certainly was considered by many to be so offensive that they crucified him. My point is, he had the right of Deity to speak to them the way he did, and he knew full well how they would react. But he wasn't goading them; he was exposing their hardened hearts. You and I cannot read hearts or minds; we must be very careful and leave all judging to Christ. As for judgmental cancel culture today; some people have committed suicide as a direct result of it, and its poison is getting stronger the more it spreads around.

I am certainly not defending cancel culture! I'm just not exactly sure why it's relevant. Is it because we don't need to worry about offending those who will be offended unreasonably? Or something else?

@DarkMalthorp Indeed, you are not. Christians need not be worried about cancel culture, or of appropriately applying words of scripture to groups, or individuals because God is our judge. The one thing we do need to always remember is that Jesus said we would be judged for every careless/idle word. Mat.12:36. A good motto text for users of this site?

Matthew 5:21-22 CSB

You have heard that it was said to our ancestors, Do not murder, and whoever murders will be subject to judgment. But I tell you, everyone who is angry with his brother or sister will be subject to judgment. Whoever insults his brother or sister, will be subject to the court. Whoever says, ‘You fool!’ will be subject to hellfire.

Look at how Jesus is matching up the ‘crimes’ to ‘punishments’ in Matthew  5:21-22.

whoever murders will be subject to judgment


everyone who is angry with his brother or sister will be subject to judgment

Firstly, you will see that Jesus equates murder and anger with the same punishment. This is not a common association and anger is a feeling while Murder is an act. Jesus could be referring to the heart being what matters the most to God, as many would likely conclude.
Could he be referring to all anger?

We know Jesus was angry and he didn’t sin.
Some manuscripts add “anger without a cause”, which raises the question, when is there anger without a cause? A just cause one could add. But what is just? The clause ends up not answering anything and it could just be an addition from a misguided attempt at clarity.
The phrase angry with his brother could link to the first man who was furious with his brother and then committed murder, Cain.

Genesis 4:5 CSB

Cain was furious, and he looked despondent.

The kind of anger Jesus is equating to murder would aptly then be the feeling behind the act, murderous rage. To find more evidence supporting this, I looked at the looking at the words used (using the same words can mean a reference), but Genesis has an additional word exceedingly angry. But this is also the first murder and anger (rage) is part of it. I also find the next part interesting though I can’t make any implications to support a link from it. God mentions the anger and what could happen.—
Genesis 4:6–7 CSB

6 Then the LORD said to Cain, “Why are you furious? And why do you look despondent? 7 If you do what is right, won’t you be accepted? But if you do not do what is right, sin is crouching at the door. Its desire is for you, but you must rule over it.”

The second and third crimes are calling someone “Raca” and “Fool (Greek. mōros)”. Depending on the resource, the former means blockhead and is a common term or is much worse and means worthless. The latter could be blockhead as well or just dull.
There may be a decrease in intensity from the first crime to the third, from murderous rage to harmless (common) words with or without feeling.

subject to judgment… the court… hellfire.

There is possibly an escalation of punishments.
The different authors of TDNT both vary on there being such a pattern of crimes or punishments. Taken from the abridged version1—

The structure of Mt. 5:21–22 shows that the reference is to three ascending forms of the same penalty rather than to three courts, and that the sins that are equivalent to murder are all sins of the tongue arranged in a kind of crescendo: Whoso is angry, says “blockhead,” or says “fool,” deserves to be punished with death, to be condemned to death, to suffer death in hell...—J. Jeremias


Since there is no real crescendo in the passage, since the two terms of abuse are virtually synonymous, and since the first court (krísis) comprises the supreme human and ultimate divine judgment, what we have is a threefold statement which achieves its effect by repetition.

Regardless if there is a pattern, Jesus is possibly either reversing the matching of crimes to punishments (harmless words have the harshest punishments) or at the very least, messing it up. This could indicate that our ordering of crimes by intensities is irrelevant or at least incorrect. Reversing the common order would be sound the most provocative to hearers, and make one reconsider what one is focusing on and what really matters to God could be different.
So what then, is the true sin?
The source, most likely the heart or our general posture to other humans is possibly the focus here. What really matters to God could be the feeling or attitude behind the acts and words, regardless of how harmless (or harsh) they are on the outside.
Going with the meaning of “Raca”, which at worse could mean “worthless”, considering someone worthless could be the real sin. Going with murderous rage, considering someone’s life yours to take, could be the real sin, and such a superiority complex.
Such a conclusion can explain how Jesus can insult someone “a blind fool“ or be angry and still not sin. He can still be valuing them and the anger could be coming from disappointed love.
In conclusion, I am quoting J. Jeremias again from the TDNT to support the warning against feelings.

This paradox whereby apparently harmless words are put on a par with murder shows how very serious sins of the tongue are in God’s eyes, and it carries a warning against ill feelings that may seem innocuous but poison relationships.


1 Kittel, G., Friedrich, G. and Bromiley, G.W. (1985) Theological Dictionary of the New Testament, Abridged in One Volume. Grand Rapids, MI: W.B. Eerdmans.
2 This was first bought to my attention by the article Bible Project: Murder and Contempt

Welcome to Christianity.SE! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and how it is different than others. I would also recommend reading the Help Center's sections on asking and answering questions.

How to add citation links o.o?

The Editing Help page has a few ways to add links to your content.

What is the proper use of insults?
First of all, let us look at the text of Matthew 5:22.
The Koine Greek text, according to Westcott and Hort, reads:

εγω δε λεγω υμιν οτι πας ο οργιζομενος τω αδελφω αυτου ενοχος εσται τη κρισει ος δ αν ειπη τω αδελφω αυτου ρακα ενοχος εσται τω συνεδριω ος δ αν ειπη μωρε ενοχος εσται εις την γεενναν του πυρος.

In the King James Version of the Bible the text reads:

But I say unto you, That whosoever is angry with his brother without a cause shall be in danger of the judgment: and whosoever shall say to his brother, Raca, shall be in danger of the council: but whosoever shall say, Thou fool, shall be in danger of hell fire.

The above text is seemingly at odds with other statements the Lord Jesus has made throughout the Gospel narratives as your question points out.
In Matthew 5:22 is the only passage in the Bible where the term raca is used. Raca comes from the Aramaic term reqa. It seems that it was a derogatory expression meaning “empty-headed,” insinuating a person’s stupidity or inferiority.
Jesus not only warns us against expressing unrighteous anger, which can lead to murder, but clearly commands that disparaging denunciations and name-calling be avoided. Such abusive words reveal the true intents of one’s heart and mind for which we will be held in judgment: “I the LORD search the heart and examine the mind, to reward each person according to their conduct, according to what their deeds deserve” (Jeremiah 17:10; cf. 1 Samuel 16:7; 1 Chronicles 28:9).
Dr. Robert Charles Sproul offers insights into this dilemma that may have been overlooked by other Biblical Scholars!

Major theological traditions have all looked to the law of God, especially the Ten Commandments, as the basis for ethics. Creeds and catechisms devote much space to expositing the Ten Commandments and what they tell us to do and what not to do. This might strike some people as strange. A great deal of popular non-Christian thinking portrays Jesus as someone who told us only to “love one another,” allowing us to define love for ourselves. Yet, even Christians can miss the coherence between a law-based ethic and the teaching of Jesus. After all, some texts seem to indicate that Jesus opposed the law of God, at least on a cursory reading.
Today we will consider one text that might call into question our Savior’s commitment to the law of God. In Matthew 5:21–26, Jesus seems to contrast or even oppose the sixth commandment. It is almost as if He is willing to set aside the law against murder in favor of His teaching against hatred. “You have heard. . . . But I say . . .” (vv. 21–22) certainly seems as if it could be a contradiction.
However, as Dr. R.C. Sproul frequently cautioned us, we must be careful students of Scripture and not just surface-level readers of the text. Looking closely at the passage, we see that our Lord by no means was seeking to overturn the sixth commandment. Note that He opens His teaching with “you have heard that it was said,” not “it is written.” This indicates that our Lord is not actually quoting Scripture as Scripture. When Jesus and the Apostles do that, they say “it is written” or something like “in the Scriptures” (Matt. 4:4; 21:42; Rom. 1:17; 1 Peter 1:16). The more general, “you have heard that it was said,” points not to the actual biblical text but to what others have said about the text. In other words, Jesus is alluding to the interpretation of the passage, particularly the interpretation of the Pharisees. His goal is to show where the Pharisees’ oral tradition was wrong.
Significantly, the Pharisees were content with a mere outward observance of the law. They believed that the law against murder had been kept as long as one did not actually kill someone else. But the law against murder forbids everything that tends toward murder, including unjust and uncontrolled anger. Jesus is not contradicting the sixth commandment but pointing out that keeping it involves more than just refraining from actual murder. He is saying that we keep the sixth commandment only if we also put hatred to death in our hearts. - Jesus and the Law of God


Regarding a practical principle, just remember two things: truth and context. The act of murder is prohibited, and not all killings. Only an unjust killing is a murder, a sinful act. Thus, what differentiates a rightful killing is its truth and context. So is the principle for all communication in regard to debates. No two persons and context are equal and same; and for judging a narrative, we need to study its context as to who is right (John 7:24). I intentionally avoid my own explanation because the topic of insulting our enemies is very politically incorrect in this Western world dominated by a pacifist Marxism. The Bible references are taken from Sam Shamoun, a polemic against Islam (article unknown). Proverbs 1:20-26; 1 Kings 18:20-29; Philippians 3:2-3; Titus 1:10-13 ; 2Peter 2:12, 19-22; Romans 12:17-21, Colossians 4:6, Ecclesiastes 3:1-8
Ecclesiastes 3:1-3 ESV

1For everything there is a season, and a time for every matter under heaven: 2a time to be born, and a time to die; a time to plant, and a time to pluck up what is planted; 3a time to kill, and a time to heal; a time to break down, and a time to build up;

Matthew 7:6

“Do not give dogs what is holy, and do not throw your pearls before pigs, lest they trample them underfoot and turn to attack you.

Ephesians 5:7-11 ESV

7Therefore do not become partners with them; 8for at one time you were darkness, but now you are light in the Lord. Walk as children of light 9(for the fruit of light is found in all that is good and right and true), 10and try to discern what is pleasing to the Lord. 11Take no part in the unfruitful works of darkness, but instead expose them.

Jude 1:22-23 ESV

22And have mercy on those who doubt; 23save others by snatching them out of the fire; to others show mercy with fear, hating even the garment stained by the flesh.

Matt 18:6

but whoever causes one of these little ones who believe in me to sin, it would be better for him to have a great millstone fastened around his neck and to be drowned in the depth of the sea.

Gal 1:10 NLT

Obviously, I'm not trying to win the approval of people, but of God. If pleasing people were my goal, I would not be Christ's servant.

Additionally, it should be noted that the believers are to be judged more severely or harshly than the unbelievers (non-Christians); and the people of NT are to be judged severely than the OT people. Our judgment should be relative to the context of persons as well. Princple of relative judgment, "From everyone who has been given much, much will be demanded; and from the one who has been entrusted with much, much more will be asked.". Reference: Matthew 11:20-24; Hebrews 10:26-29; James 3:1; 1 Timothy 3:1-7; Luke 12:47-48.
